# Moodle Video Stream from AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, moodle

I was just wondering if there is a configuration so that the Moodle's objects (eg: video, images, ppt, pdf, etc) for the course content can be uploaded into AWS S3 and also streamed from S3.

I have installed the plugging and uploaded it into S3. But when I test it by deleting the object in S3, I am still able to view the object via the browser.

Anyone has any idea how I can ensure that the Video/Picture comes direct from AWS S3?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you using **S3 repository plugin** that **Download S3 files to moodle**. That's why you still able to view object from **moodle**.